# How do I define my setting (list) in my code?

Tags: python, variables

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I am sure it's a simple fix, but does anyone know why it says my setting is not defined?

I apologise this is literally my first time coding period, but we have to do a project for my class so thank you all for those who answer and help me.

````py
import random
#Startup message
print("Greetings adventurer!")

readerName = input("What is your name? ")

print("Hello there " + readerName + ", let's begin your one of a kind adventure...")

print("We can visit one these places: Outer Space, the Ocean, Medieval time, the Old West, or the Future.")
placeTogo = input("Where would you like to go? ")

placetheme = (["Outer Space, the Ocean, Medieval time, the old West, the future"])
if placetheme =="Outer Space":
    setting=random.choice(["the dark space","an asteroid belt","a planet covered with ice","a planet surrounded by lava","a planet made of candy","an aliens, home planet","a wormhole"])
    protagonist=random.choice(["human","robot","monkey","alien", "blob","amoeba","space robot"])
    antagonist=random.choice(["a female","a male","an alien colony","a lone alien","an artifical intellgence","a glitch in space","an invading army","evil mutated fungus","a lost robot"])
conflict=random.choice(["wanted to protect ","fought against ","tried to stop ","tried to be friends with ","traveled with ","tried to run from ","race with ","create a new home with"])

end=random.choice(["It ended well.","It ended not well.","Lived happily ever after.","It ended with betrayl.","It was victorious.","In the end, nothing changed.","Gave up.", "It ended in tragedy."])
print("We've arrived in",placetheme,"specifically in",setting,", where we met a ", protagonist, "who", conflict, antagonist,".",end)```

line 19, in <module>
    print("We've arrived in",placetheme,"specifically in",setting,", where we met a ", protagonist, "who", conflict, antagonist,".",end)
````

`NameError: name 'setting' is not defined`

Comment: Please add the Traceback (error message) that you're receiving when you run this code.

Comment: `placetheme` never equals `"Outer Space"`. `placetheme` is a list containing a single string containing, among others, the phrase `"Outer Space"`. Perhaps you meant to create a list of phrases/terms? Then make sure the comma's separating the terms are outside of double quotes. E.g.: `placetheme = ["Outer Space", "the Ocean", "Medieval time", ...]`. Even then, the comparison should be `if "Outer Space" in placetheme":`, to test that `"Outer Space"` exists in the list.

Comment: You also ask for `placeTogo` to be entered by the user, but you never use that. Do you intend to compare `if placeTogo == "Outer Space":`?

Comment: You need to initialize the variable setting before it is being used inside if condition.

Comment: Try to explain to yourself, in plain English words, step by step, the intended logic of the code. Specifically focus on what *doesn't* happen, and on how the program will react when e.g. `if` conditions are *not* satisfied.

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I feel like your code isn't properly indented. You only define `setting` inside the `if placetheme == "Outer Space"` block, but you print it OUTSIDE of that block. If `placetheme` is anything else, `setting` would not have been created or assigned.

In fact, as it's written, `placetheme` is a list inside a tuple, and doesn't get set to `Outer Space` to be able to get into that `if` block

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change

```
if placetheme =="Outer Space":
```

to

```
if placeTogo =="Outer Space":
```

In your code `setting` is initialized in the `if` scope, and only exist when the `if` section executes. In your case the `if` section never executes, so there's no `setting` variable, but that one is later called in the last line of your code.